# css :before, why are my shapes not on top of each other

Tags: css

I would like to use the CSS `:before` selector to create a copy of my current div styles, and overlay it on top of my initial `div`. But I am unable to do this, without changing the `:before` position.

Why does this happen, and how can I assure that the position of these two is always the same?

```css
.example {
  margin: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  display: block;
}

.example:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;

}
```

```html
<div class='example'/>
```

Comment: You should be using the `::before` syntax, by the way. Note the double colon.

Comment: _"Why does this happen"_ - because the ::before pseudo element is rendered as if it was the first _child_ element of the div, and so you have stuck a 110px wide and high (5px borders on each side plus 100px width/height) child into an element that itself is just 100px by 100px, so it must overflow out of the parent. Add `overflow: hidden` to the div, and you see where the pseudo child gets cut off. _"overlay it on top of my initial div"_ - `margin:-5px` on the pseudo child would do.

Comment: Also, are you trying to get it to be directly over the `.example` div? So that you can't see the `.example` div?

Comment: This is because the :before element is positioned inside the border of the other element

Comment: @Cbroe thanks, write is up as an anwser, and I'll accept it.

Comment: @elliottregan yes, overlaying the .example div so that you can't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does this happen

Because the ::before pseudo element is rendered as if it was the first *child* element of the div, so it has to be inside the border of the parent element. It's top left static position is offset by 5px from what you perceive as the dimensions of the parent, but which is actually the border *outside* of those. That borders are rounded to be circle-shaped might confuse one's perception of things here at first glance. (Thanks DaniP for clarification.)

And so you have stuck a 110px wide and high (5px borders on each side plus 100px width/height) child into an element that itself is just 100px by 100px, so it must overflow out of the parent. Add `overflow: hidden` to the div, or an `outline`, and you see where the pseudo child gets cut off.

> overlay it on top of my initial div

For example `margin:-5px` on the pseudo child would do.

Depending on what you want to achieve in the end, it might not be the best approach. For example if the div is eventually going to contain actual (text) content, then the pseudo child would push that out of the way. As an alternative, you could position the div relative, and the pseudo child absolute, with top/left `-5px` each, that would achieve the same positioning of the child. If it needs to be behind content, add `z-index`.

Comment: Just to clarify -- Actually the offset doesn't happen for the dimensions its just because the initial position of the element isn't over the border it's always after that...even if you put an smallest element inside or use box-sizing:border-box to ensure same dimensions it will offset.

Comment: @DaniP yeah, thanks, you're right. I'll make an edit to mention that.